# Programming Arm Cortex M0 with Atmel Studio

Tags: arm, cortex-m, atmelstudio

I am planning on using the DA14581 SoC which is based on the ARM® Cortex®-M0 processor and programming it should be possible via Atmel Studio. I would like to not have to buy any other products in order to develop this product.

I have a fresh install of Atmel Studio 7 and the device is connected over UART to connect to USB.

How do I go about creating the correct file type and uploading the code to the chip?

Comment: Did you read the [list of supported devices](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/atmelstudio/supported_devices.html)?. I'd say it's very unlikely that Atmel studio supports it (and I can't find it in the list). [Keil supports DA14580](http://www.keil.com/dd/chip/6853.htm), you could at least give it a try since there is a free version for keil (assuming program size < some limit).

Comment: you can most certainly use free gnu based toolchains to cross compile for all/most flavors of arm, including the cortex-m0.

Comment: An ARM CPU core is not a device - the relevant aspects for writing useful code and programming the thing would be stuff like the memory layout, peripherals, external programming interface, etc. None of which have anything whatsoever to do with what CPU core a device happens to have, and are often very vendor-specific. You can write code for "a Cortex-M0", but without any (device-specific) peripherals to interact with the outside world it will just be an exceptionally unexciting way to turn electricity into heat. And you'll _still_ need some device-specific means of getting it onto the thing...